# solving string alignment in O(mn)

Tags: string, algorithm

I need to solve the follow problem withing O(nm).
n = |T|
m = |P|
where T,P two strings
f is a scoring function.

the algorithm should return a substring T' of T such that score(P,T') value is the maximum.

score(A,B) is the max val for alignment A and B according f.

I know I can get it from DIST matrix which is a Monge matrix if f is discrete (meaning the diagonals of the matrix has weights not larger than C which is a constant, and the horizontal and vertical edges is 0 or some other constant), but in this case the f is a general function from (sigma * {-})x(sigma * {-}) to R (where '-' is a gap).

any ideas?

Comment: This smells like homework. Is it?

Comment: How does brute force sound to you?

Comment: I need to present some string algorithms and I came across waterman's algorithm, Hirschberg's algorithm and some others. but everybody succeed to solve problems like this one in O(mn) with a lot of assumption on the scoring function. I simply want to present a better one if it exists.

Comment: bruth force is not good because it would run in O((n^2) * m)

Comment: yes, but needleman-wunsh also assume things on f as I describe above.

Comment: it only assumes that f('-', whatever) = f(whatever, '-') = some constant. and even that assumption doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: also, this algorithm seem to solve only the alignment problem and not the problem I've described above. doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've noticed that there are several algorithms that compute a shortest path in a graph whose arcs are (i, j) → (i + 1, j), (i + 1, j + 1), (i, j + 1). The most general form of this algorithm would allow every arc length to be specified separately, with the following meanings.

- (i, j) → (i + 1, j): cost of aligning the (i+1)th letter of P with a gap in T
- (i, j) → (i + 1, j + 1): cost of aligning the (i+1)th letter of P with the (j+1)th letter of T
- (i, j) → (i, j + 1): cost of aligning a gap in P with the (j+1)th letter of T

Costs can be negative. To solve your substring problem, make the costs of all of the (i, j) → (i, j + 1) arcs zero so that we can delete from T without penalty.

Comment: After 6 hours I still can't realize how to do so in O(nm) with your suggestion. can you explain some more? thanks.

Comment: It's an acyclic graph, so instead of using a heap we can visit the nodes in any topological order and relax each outgoing arc of the node we're currently at. (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), ..., (1, 0), (1, 1), ..., (m, n) is one possible order, as is (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), ..., (0, 1), (1, 1), ..., (m, n), as are many others.

Comment: Oh, substring rather than subsequence. Keep the costs for gaps in P, but add length-zero arcs from a new source s to (0, i) for all i and to a new sink t from (m, i) for all i.